# OutputStream stuck?

Tags: java, file, io

I've got a little problem with a file-transfer-system that has never happened to me before.

```
@Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                String message = (String) new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()).readObject();
                if (message.startsWith("message="))
                {
                    message = message.replaceFirst("message=", "");
                    frame.addLine(message);
                }
                else if (message.startsWith("file="))
                {
                    final String file = message.replaceFirst("file=", "");
                    int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame, "Do you want to download \"" + file + "\"?", "Download", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
                    if (selection == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                    {
                        JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                        jFileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

                        int rValue = jFileChooser.showDialog(frame, "Öffnen");

                        if (rValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                        {
                            new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()).writeObject("file_confirm=" + file);

                            String selectedDir = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();

                            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(selectedDir, file));

                            try
                            {

                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                                for (int c = 0; (c = socket.getInputStream().read(buffer)) > 0;)
                                {
                                    out.write(buffer, 0, c);
                                    System.out.println(c);
                                }

                                System.out.println("test1");

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                System.out.println("test2");
                                out.flush();
                                out.close();
                                System.out.println("test3");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (message.startsWith("kick()"))
                {
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                    frame.dispose();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You have been kicked!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                else if (message.startsWith("clear()"))
                {
                    frame.clear();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Connection timed out!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

    }
```

This prints out (filesize 31 KB):

around 30 times 1024 (as expected)

382

4

10

4

10

4

10

----- 4 and 10 goes on forever until I terminate the application -----

It always repeats this 4 and 10 no matter what file I use. So I figured out the problem myself it gets stuck in the for-loop, but why?

---

If you have the same problem I just wanna let you know that there are two ways to fix it.

1. The anwser below
2. a simple

   if (c < buffer.length) break;

will fix it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to swing operation from separate thread you have make it thread safe. to make it thread safe use

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
               //put  your swing operation here
            }
        });



EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            int selection = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                                    "Do you want to download \"" + file + "\"?",
                                    "Download", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null,
                                    JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
                            if (selection == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                                JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                                jFileChooser
                                        .setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

                                int rValue = jFileChooser.showDialog(frame, "Öffnen");

                                if (rValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                                    new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
                                            .writeObject("file_confirm=" + file);

                                    String selectedDir = jFileChooser.getSelectedFile()
                                            .getAbsolutePath();

                                    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                                            selectedDir, file));

                                    try {

                                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                                        for (int c = 0; (c = socket.getInputStream()
                                                .read(buffer)) > 0;) {
                                            out.write(buffer, 0, c);
                                            System.out.println(c);
                                        }

                                        System.out.println("test1");

                                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                                        ex.printStackTrace();
                                    } finally {
                                        System.out.println("test2");
                                        out.flush();
                                        out.close();
                                        System.out.println("test3");
                                    }
                                }
                            }//  
                        }
                    });
```

same for other swing operation

Comment: if it helps you, approve my answer :)

Comment: I just realized that I can't do that, because I have a Runnable that waits for input from the socket. If the input-object is a specific type it should ask where to save a file and send a confirmation to the server that the client is ready to receive the bytes. But if I put this filewriting task in a Runnable the Runnable that invokes the filewriting asks for more data. Then the data that should go to the filewriting task goes to the other Runnable.. It's hard to explain. I'll update the question with the full code. First I thought this part is enough :S

Comment: Just a little thing to discuss:

I fixed it on another way too. I never thought about it, because it was to easy/to obvious to be good. Just put a
-->
if (c < 1024) break; <-- in the for loop and it works fine too.